# How to limit the amount of buttons Watir collects?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, twitter, watir

I'm collecting the follow buttons of twitter. How can I limit the buttons to just 30 buttons not everything on the page ?

```
    #Collect the "Follow" buttons
    browser.spans(:class => ['user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button']).each do |b|

        #Click them! One by one.
        b.click

        # Generate random sleep period
        r = Random.rand(4...7)

        #Sleep so not to appear like a bot.
        sleep(r)
        # end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [#shift](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shift) method

```
browser.spans(:class => ['user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button'])
    .to_a
    .shift(30)
    .each do |b|

  b.click

end
```

Answer (score 3):

Element collections include Enumerable, so you can use the [#take](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-take):

```
browser.spans(:class => ['user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button']).take(30).each do |b|
    b.click
end
```